# Return.portfolio function for re-balancing with time series of weights

Tags: portfolio-management, performanceanalytics, rebalancing

I am using the Return.portfolio function from the PerformanceAnalytics R package in order to re-balance the portfolio based on different frequencies (i.e. daily, weekly monthly, etc.) using a time series of weights. The function works fine when using a static weight-vector such as `c(0.6, 0.2, 0.2)` but when using the **time series weight matrix** the function produces the same result for all re-balancing frequencies, i.e.

`r.p.dynRP.d = Return.portfolio(ret["1997-01-30/2018-01-05"], weights=weight_matrix, rebalance_on="days")`

yields the same result as

`r.p.dynRP.y = Return.portfolio(ret["1997-01-30/2018-01-05"], weights=weight_matrix, rebalance_on="years")`

`ret` and `weight_matrix` are both **xts objects** with the same dimensions and the same `indexclass=date`.

I think the function re-balances daily for all frequencies. Any idea why this is case? Is there perhaps a better way for the calculation of periodic re-balancing based on changing portfolio weights?

Answer (score 1):

It actually works if you convert the **(time series) weight matrix** to the frequency you want to use for re-balancing using, e.g. `apply.weekly(weight_matrix)`. The return matrix should still be daily data. I.e. the following code worked for me:

```
weight_matrix.w=apply.weekly(weight_matrix, last)
r.p.dynRP.w = Return.portfolio(ret, weights=weight_matrix.w)
```